# Change Filtering Type of Telerik GridViewComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-grid, datagridviewcombobox

I have a telerik GridView contains ComboBox column, the filtering type is 'StartWith'. and I want to change it to 'Contains'.

How could i do it?

Comment: Did you tried anything so far? Please read [faq] and [ask]

Comment: Dear @Soner. Thank you. Yes i have tried several things. I have tried filter discriptor, I could not reach my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Check here [Telerik Grid Filtering guide](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/generalfeatures/filtering/defaultcs.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas, kindly note that it is a WinForm application. And i want to search in a combobox column inside the gridview. Not the whole gridview. Hope u can help

Comment: Look in the documentation wich is found here. http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-overview.html. Everything should be explained here